# Determining an MLE

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, point-estimation

I am trying to find the MLE of $\theta$ for $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ with the following pdf:

$$f(x|\theta) = \frac{\log(\theta)}{\theta - 1} \theta^{x}$$

I determined the joint density and got:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\log(\theta)}{\theta - 1} \theta^{x_i} = \frac{(\log(\theta))^n}{(\theta - 1)^n}\theta^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

When taking the log of the equation, I got:

$$n\log(\log(\theta)) - n\log(\theta-1) + \sum x_i \log(\theta)$$

Next I took the derivative with respect to $\theta$ and got:
$$\frac{\sum x_i}{\theta} + \frac{n}{\theta\log(\theta)} - \frac{n}{\theta - 1}$$

I am now trying to set this equal to zero and solve for $\theta$, however, I am finding that I am getting stuck with this. I tried plugging into wolfram alpha as well and it did not come up with a solution. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: You log-likelihood function is missing the production $n$ on the two last terms,  i.e., $l(\theta)=n\log(\log\theta)-n\log(\theta-1)+\log \theta\sum X_i$

Comment: I see @Ami edited the likelihood and now it looks fine

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha It was a good comment, though - w/o parentheses, it was at best ambiguous.

Comment: Maybe it would help to define $\kappa=-\log(\theta)$ so that the density becomes proportional to the familiar, well-understood, and extremely well documented $\exp(-\kappa x).$

Comment: @whuber isn’t the domain of $x$ different, though?

Comment: @Ami Everything I wrote implicitly assumed *everything* else remained the same, including the restriction to $0\lt x \lt 1.$  It results in a truncated Exponential distribution.

Comment: Do you have a function for MATLAB which generates samples? If you do, just draw this 1D function. Does it cross 0?